# multipart request with multer does not work with bodyparser true parameters

Tags: node.js, multer

My code is as show below:

app.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(busboyBodyParser({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.post('/registerFoodTruck',foodtruckservice.registerFoodTruck);
```

foodtruckservice.js

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var path = require('path');
var upload = multer();
var awsUpload = require('./../config/fileUpload.js');
var Promise = require('promise');
var profile_image = '';
var foodTruck = require('./../model/foodtruck.js');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './public/images')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        profile_image = file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname);
        callback(null, profile_image)
    }
});

var registerFoodTruck = function(req, res) {

    upload = multer({
        limits: {
            fileSize: 1000000,
            files: 1
        },
        storage: storage,
        fileFilter: function(req, file, callback) {
            var ext = path.extname(file.originalname)
            if (ext !== '.png' && ext !== '.jpg' && ext !== '.gif' && ext !== '.jpeg') {
                return callback(res.end('Only images are allowed'), null)
            }
            callback(null, true);
        }
    }).single('profile_img');
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        var foodtruck_name = req.body.foodtruck_name;
        var foodtruck_location = req.body.foodtruck_location;
        var foodtruck_tag = req.body.foodtruck_tag;
        var foodtruck_start_time = req.body.foodtruck_starting_timing;
        var foodtruck_close_time = req.body.foodtruck_closing_timing;
        var cusine = req.body.foodtruck_cusine;
        console.log("foodname" + foodtruck_name);
        if ((foodtruck_name == null) || (foodtruck_name.trim() == '')) {
            res.json({
                status: '404',
                message: 'Please enter valid foodtruck name'
            });
        } else if ((foodtruck_location == null) || (foodtruck_location.trim() == '')) {
            res.json({
                status: '404',
                message: 'Please enter valid location'
            });
        } else if ((cusine == null) || (cusine.trim() == '')) {
            res.json({
                status: '404',
                message: 'Please enter valid cusine'
            });
        } else {

            var truck = new foodTruck();
            truck.foodtruck_location = foodtruck_location,
                truck.foodtruck_name = foodtruck_name,
                truck.foodtruck_tag = foodtruck_tag,
                truck.foodtruck_open_status = 1,
                truck.foodtruck_starting_timing = foodtruck_start_time,
                truck.foodtruck_closing_timing = foodtruck_close_time,
                truck.foodtruck_cusine = cusine;

            truck.save();

            res.json({
                status: '200',
                message: 'Thanks for registering with quflip'
            });
        }
    });
}
```

My input parameters are as shown below in screenshot:
[image: input parameters]

Now what happens here is if I make it only "x-www-formurlencoded" , it works fine. But when I am using it for multipart data, it is not able to recognize the body parameters from request. So how can I have successful multipart request?

Comment: Why are you parsing the request twice? You have `busboyBodyParser` which I presume is just a `multer()` instance, and then you have another inside `registerFoodTruck()`.

Comment: Secondly, you should post the relevant frontend portion of your code (e.g. html form or XHR code, etc.)

Comment: @mscdex , please find my input parameters in updated question. There is one screenshots in which they are mentioned